# How to pass function parameters in sql query in R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, function, parameter-passing

I have the following function in `R`:

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};
                              server=myServer;database=myDB;
                              trusted_connection=true')
func <- function(x){
     sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select attr from myTable where cond = x')
}
```

I want to know how to pass the `x` parameter to the `where` condition for the `cond` attribute. For example, I want to calculate `func(10)`, then the query must be:

```
select attr from myTable where cond = 10
```

Comment: Please properly define what you mean by *parameter* as there is a concept called SQL parameterization which the below majority of answers do not employ except for one for the RODBC package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with `paste`:

```
func <- function(x){
  sqlQuery(dbhandle, paste('select attr from myTable where cond =', x))
}
```

Comment: Warning: This does not take sql injection into account https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4):

when using `RODBC`, I prefer to use parameterized queries. This becomes more valuable when you are passing character strings, as this avoids SQL Injection.

```
library(RODBCext)

sqlExecute(dbhandle, 
           "select attr from myTable where cond = ?",
           data = list(cond = 10),
           fetch = TRUE,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the `glue` package for these things, though it's really the same as `paste`, just prettier :

```
library(glue)

func <- function(x){
     sqlQuery(dbhandle, glue('select attr from myTable where cond = {x}'))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In this simple case you could even use `dplyr` itself:

```
library(dplyr)

func <- function(x) {
     tbl(dbhandle, "myTable") %>%
       select(attr) %>%
       filter(cond == x) %>%
       collect()
}
```